# how to manually set a task to run in a gae queue for the second time

Tags: google-app-engine, queue, task

I have a task that runs in GAE queue.
according to my logic, I want to determine if the task will run again or not.

I don't want it do be normally executed by the queue and then to put it again in the queue
because I want to have the ability to check the "X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount"
and quit trying after several attempts.

To my understanding it seems that the only case that a task will re-executed is when an internal GAE error will happen (or If my code will take too long in a "DeadlineExceededException" cases..(And I don't want to hold the code "hostage" for that long :) )

How can I re-enter a task to the queue in a manner that GAE will set X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount ++ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically retry / restart a task using a self.error() in python.
From the docs: App engine retries a task by returning any HTTP status code outside of the range 200–299

And at the beginning of the task you can test for the number of retries using:

```
retries = int(self.request.headers['X-Appengine-Taskretrycount'])
if retries < 10 :
    self.error(409)
    return
```